# Cómo atrapar reject de una promesa en una funcion async

Tags: javascript, promesas

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
const cargarArchivo = async(req, res = response) => {
  
    // Imagenes
    try {
    const pathCompleto = await subirArchivo(req.files, undefined, 'textos');

    res.json({
        path: pathCompleto
    })
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: error
        })
    }

   
}

const subirArchivo = (files, extensionesValidas = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'], carpeta = '') => {


  if (!files){
    return Promise.reject('No se encontró ningun archivo');
  }


    const {archivo} = files;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const nombreCortado = archivo.name.split('.');
        const extension = nombreCortado[nombreCortado.length - 1];
    
       
    
        if (!extensionesValidas.includes(extension)){
            return reject(`La extension ${extension} no es valida`);
        }
    
       
        const nombreTemp = uuidv4() + '.' + extension;
        const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, '../uploads/', carpeta,nombreTemp);
      
        archivo.mv(uploadPath, (err) =>{
          if (err)
            reject('sii error');
      
          resolve(nombreTemp);
        });
    });

}
```

El problema lo tengo en la funcion subirArchivo, cuando no está definido la variable files, entra al primer condicional, y quiero regresar un Promise.reject para atraparlo con el catch de la funcion cargarArchivo, pero no lo atrapa y solo lo muestra como una excepcion que termina la aplicacion, sin embargo si el reject ocurre dentro del return new Promise alli si es atrapado por el catch de la funcion cargarArchivo. Lei la documentación y Promise.reject retorna una promesa y deberia ser capturada en el catch, por qué razon no está funcionando?

Comment: Basta con que metas tu condición dentro de la Promesa, de esta forma siempre estarás rechazando la misma Promesa que devuelve tu función. ¿Alguna razón especial para tener la condición fuera? Por otro lado, acostumbra a usar `return resolve( ... )` y `return reject( ... )`, de esta forma es más explícito que la función devuelve un rechazo o una resolución, y menos propenso a errores. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me da la idea que el ejemplo que pones no hace lo mismo que tu código real, porque si yo reproduzco tu flujo (simplificado), sí entra al catch, tanto cuando rechaza antes de instanciar la promesa como dentro de ésta, incluso en el stack separado que se crea en un setTimeout:

```js
const cargarArchivo = async(files) => {
  try {
    const pathCompleto = await subirArchivo(files );

    console.log(pathCompleto);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Catched!');
    console.error(error);
  }
}

const subirArchivo = (files ) => {
  if (!files) {
    return Promise.reject('No se encontró ningun archivo');
  }
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     setTimeout(()=>reject('tiempo!'),1000);
  });
}

cargarArchivo(null);

cargarArchivo('archivo');
```

Si usas `throw new Error('mensaje')` también lo atraparías al llamalo en el scope principal de tu función, pero no si arrojas un error en un stack distinto:

```js
const cargarArchivo = async(files) => {
  try {
    const pathCompleto = await subirArchivo(files );

    console.log(pathCompleto);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Catched!');
    console.error(error);
  }
}

const subirArchivo = (files ) => {
  if (!files) {
    throw new Error('No se encontró ningun archivo');
  }
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     setTimeout(()=>{
        throw new Error('tiempo!')
     },1000);
  });
}

cargarArchivo(null);

cargarArchivo('archivo');
```

De lo cual sólo cabe suponer que en alguna parte se está usando `throw` en vez de `reject`. De todos modos, un reject debiera recibir un error y no un string. O sea

```
return Promise.reject(new Error('no se encontró...'));
```

en vez de

```
return Promise.reject('no se encontró...');
```

Porque la idea es que lo que reciba el `catch (err) {...}` o el `.catch(err => {...}` tenga propiedades `message` y `stack`.